# cURL returns different HTML than a browser

Tags: curl

I'm trying to get the contents of the following URL using cURL

curl -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.1.4) Gecko/20091030 Gentoo Firefox/3.5.4' "http://md.com/specialties/neurology"

However it returns me a different HTML when I visit the website in Mozilla.

What am I missing?

Comment: tried: curl -H "Accept: text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, */*" -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.1.4) Gecko/20091030 Gentoo Firefox/3.5.4' "http://md.com/specialties/neurology"

doesn't work. 

How can I fake a browser request using curl?

Comment: I am sorry. I don't follow what other headers I should include. Could you give me an example that works for the above URL? Thanks.

Comment: You should probably check out [this blog post by curl's author](http://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2015/11/23/copy-as-curl/). And don't forget to follow redirects with `-L`.